# Expression for combining 3d and 2d matrices into resulting 2d matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, hadamard-product

I would like to know if there is a convenient mathematical expression for the following.

I want to construct a (n x n) matrix $\mathbf{C}$ for which i know that each column $\mathbf{C}_i$ is equal to $(\mathbf{A}_i \circ \mathbf{B})\mathbf{1}$. Matrix $\mathbf{B}$ is (n x n) whereas $\mathbf{1}$ is a (n x 1) vector of ones. Further, $\mathbf{A}$ is 3-dimensional (n x n x n) where i consider $\mathbf{A}_i$ to be the (n x n) submatrix at level $i$ of $\mathbf{A}$. Equivalently, if $\mathbf{A}$ would be viewed as a (1 x n) vector of 2d matrices, $\mathbf{A}_i$ would be the (n x n) matrix at position $(1,i)$ of that vector. To conclude, the $\circ$ operator indicates the Schur (element-wise) product.

Ideally, but i'm sure wrongfully, it would be nice to write $\mathbf{C} = (\mathbf{A} \circ \mathbf{B})\mathbf{U}$, with $\mathbf{U}$ being the (n x n) matrix of ones, but i think columns of $\mathbf{U}$ will not just correctly "hop over" to each level $i$ submatrix of $\mathbf{A}$ in constructing $\mathbf{C}$.

Is there a correct way for expressing $\mathbf{C}$, maybe via tensor algebra?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that each column $\mathbf{C}_i$ adheres to $(\mathbf{A}_i \circ \mathbf{B})\mathbf{1}$"? Do you mean that $\mathbf C_i$ **is equal to** $(\mathbf A_i \circ \mathbf B) \mathbf 1$, or is there some other relationship you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, equal to. I've corrected the text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "adheres to" means the same as "is equal to".

Let $\text{vec}$ denote the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and $\text{diag}(M_1,\dots,M_k)$ the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Direct_sum) of matrices. We can write
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf C) = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf A_1 \circ \mathbf B, \dots, \mathbf A_n \circ \mathbf B) \mathbf 1_{n^2 \times 1}
$$

Comment: Ok, I see the mechanics. Then, to retrieve C, probably the inverse of the vectorization operator could be applied, like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122442/455291

Comment: @dixity Yes, that's the idea