# If I know the ODE of a PSD matrix, how can I find the ODE of its square root matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

I know that the ODE that describes how the covariance matrix $P$ changes over time is
$$ \dot{P} = A P + P A^T $$
where both $A$ and $P$ are time-varying $n \times n$ matrices.

Since $P$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix, there exists a symmetric PSD matrix $R$ such that $P = RR$, which is generally called the square root of $P$.
I would like to derive the ODE that describes how $R$ changes over time, that is
$$ \dot{R} = f(R, A, \dots) $$
but I do not know how to find that right-hand side $f$ or if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of $P\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}\,$ with $R$
$$\eqalign{
P &= RR \\
\dot P &= AP + PA^T \\
\dot RR + R\dot R  &= ARR + RRA^T \\
}$$
Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
r &= {\rm vec}(R),\qquad \dot r = {\rm vec}(\dot R) \\
}$$
Then vectorize the differential relationship using Kronecker products
$$\eqalign{
(R\otimes I)\dot r + (I\otimes R)\dot r
  &= (R\otimes A)r + (A\otimes R)r \\
\Big((R\otimes I) + (I\otimes R)\Big)\dot r
  &= \Big((R\otimes A) + (A\otimes R)\Big)r \\
\dot r
  &= \Big((R\otimes I) + (I\otimes R)\Big)^{-1}
     \Big((R\otimes A) + (A\otimes R)\Big)r \\
\dot R &= {\rm Unvec}(\dot r) \\
}$$
In many programming languages (e.g. *Matlab*, *Julia*, etc) the Unvec operation is available as the `Reshape()` function. There is also an [algebraic formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805565/what-is-the-inverse-of-the-mboxvec-operator/3122442#3122442) for this operation.

Perhaps a better approach is to directly employ the vector-valued ODE
$\;\dot r=f(R,A)$

Comment: Yes, vectorization is probably the best (only?) approach. I will try it out in the next days and see if I can make it work.