# How to solve $AX-XA=C\circ X$ in closed form

Tags: matrix-equations, sylvester-equation

Given a hermitian matrix $A$ and a anti-symmetric matrix $C$, consider the matrix equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ A. - C\circ\right]X = X.A
\end{eqnarray}
where $A.B$ represents standard matrix multiplication, but $A\circ B$ is the (elementwise) Hadamard product between two matrices. Further, with $C$ being a real, anti-symmetric matrix:
\begin{eqnarray}
C_{ij}=-C_{ji}.
\end{eqnarray}
Is there a way to solve this equation for $X$ in an exact way? By using the eigenbasis of $A$ for instance, I don't arrive to any closed expression for the elements of $X$. It looks related to the Sylvester or Lyapunov equations, but I don't really know how to proceed further.

Comment: Isn't it true that for every $A,X$ there is unique $C$ such that $AX-XA=C\circ X$?

Comment: Is that a theorem? I am just referring to  the case where the $C$ is known beforehand. Following your comment, that would already imply that $C$ has the correct form, if I followed your argument correctly.

Comment: In your question, $A, X$ are known, and you are trying to find $C$. What is the real question?

Comment: No, $A$ is known but not $X$; the only known thing about $X$ is that it is hermitian, and so is $A$. So, knowing $A,C$, how to determine $X$. I rephrased the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$You can use Kronecker products to create a vector equation which will yield a closed-form solution if a solution exists.
$$\eqalign{
&AX - XA = C\circ X \\
&\LR{\LR{I\otimes A} - \LR{A^T\otimes I}}\vecc{X}
   = \Diag{\vecc{C}}\vecc{X} \\
}$$
Defining some auxiliary variables allows the equation to be written more compactly
$$\eqalign{
x &= \vecc{X},\quad
B &= \Diag{\vecc{C}},\quad
M &= \LR{I\otimes A} - \LR{A^T\otimes I} \\
Mx &= Bx\\
}$$
This is a [Generalized Eigenvalue Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). $\;$This can often be reduced to an ordinary Eigenvalue Problem, if either $M$ or $B$ is invertible.

However, since $C$ is skew symmetric it has $0$s along its diagonal, so $B$ is not invertible. Similarly, $M$ is rank deficient due to the way it is constructed, so it is not invertible either.

In any case, $x$ is the eigenvector associated to the unit eigenvalue $(\l=\o),\,$ if such an eigenvalue exists. The eigenvector can then be [reconstituted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122442/357854) into the corresponding matrix solution.

Note that if $x$ is a solution, then so is any scalar multiple $\beta x.\;$  This is also true of your matrix equation, i.e. if $X$ satisfies the equation then so does $\beta X$.