# About transforming block matrices: Transposition or Vectorization?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

There are 2 matrices and the result of their product:

$X=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$

$D=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$X \cdot D=\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & a\\ c & 0 & d & 0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix}$

The desired result looks like this:

[image]

**My question:** are there alternative, simpler operators that do the desired transformation?

**My attempt:** I first vectorized the original result, then "cut and stitched" in a new way [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122442/656085]:

[image]

https://dropmefiles.com/avpwH - here is the file from Mathcad Prime 8

Comment: $(X \otimes I_3) \begin{pmatrix}D_1\\D_2\\D_3\end{pmatrix}$ where $D =  \begin{pmatrix}D_1&D_2&D_3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Exodd it doesn't work https://ibb.co/F7hDyTV

Comment: Your kronecker is defined backwards. In this case, it is $I_3\otimes X$

Comment: @Exodd It seems to work. This is a good take. Does this technique have any theoretical background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition $D$ into 8 column vectors, so $XD$ is just$[Xv_1, ... , Xv_8]$ $$X \begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}$$ is the column vector $e$ column 1 of $X$+$f$ column 2 of $X.$

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. Could you describe it in a little more detail: what is $e$ and $f$, what is the function $X + f$, etc.

Comment: ($e$ co[umn 1 of $X$) + ($f$ column 2 of $X$). Write $v_1$ as $$\begin{bmatrix} e\\f \end{bmatrix}$$.Similarly for $v_2, ... ,v_8$.

Comment: Thank you! That's cool