# How to solve the problem of trace optimization which includes Hadamard product?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, trace, hadamard-product

I have the following minimization problem, where I want to find W,
\begin{align}
&\min \mathrm{tr} (((W^TK)\circ(W^TK))^T((W^TK)\circ(W^TK))L)\\
&\text{s.t.} ~ W^TKHKW = I
\end{align}
where $\circ$ means the Hadamard product,and the L ,H and K are both semi-positive definite and symmetric.
By taking the derivative of the objective function with respect to W and using the Lagrange multiplier, I get the following formula
\begin{align}
&2K[[L((KW)\circ(KW))]\circ(KW)]=KHKW\phi
\end{align}
where the $\phi$ is the Lagrange multiplier.Then, I don't know how to go on.Or is it impossible to find the W I want?
I'd really appreciate it for any help.

Comment: Optimization problems like this, if I didn't know how to solve them, maybe I could just use the solver to find a solution, but in that case, is this derivative that I'm taking useless?Or what can I do with this derivative information if I don't know how to solve it,  Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\unvc#1{\op{unvec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}} \def\p{\partial} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\B{B^{-1}}
$Define the following matrix variables in terms of $(H,K,L)$
$$\eqalign{
X &= KW       &\qiq X^T = W^TK \\
Y &= X\odot X &\qiq Y^T = X^T\odot X^T \\
H &= C^TC     &\qiq \big\{{\rm Cholesky}\big\} \\
Z &= CX       &\qiq X = C^{-1}Z \\
}$$
Starting with an unconstrained matrix $U$, construct the semi-orthogonal matrix $Z$
$$\eqalign{
B &= B^T = \LR{U^TU}^{1/2} \\
Z &= U\B \qiq
  &Z^TZ &= \B U^TU B^{-1} = \B B^2 \B = I \\
 &&  &\doteq X^TC^TCX = W^TKHKW \\
}$$

Now calculate differentials with respect to the unconstrained variable
$$\eqalign{
B^2 &= U^TU \\
B\,dB+dB\,B &= U^TdU+dU^TU  \\
(I\otimes B+B\otimes I)\,db
 &= \LR{I\otimes U^T+(U^T\otimes I)M}du \\
db &= P\,du \\
\\
Z &= UB^{-1} \\
dZ &= dU\,\B - UB^{-1}dB\,\B \\
 &= dU\,\B - Z\,dB\,\B \\
dz &= \LR{\B\otimes I)\,du \;-\; (\B\otimes Z}\,\c{db} \\
 &= \LR{(\B\otimes I) - (\B\otimes Z)\c{P}}\,\c{du} \\
 &= Q\,du \\
\\
X &= C^{-1}Z \\
dX &= C^{-1}dZ \\
dx &= \LR{I\otimes C^{-1}}\c{dz} \\
 &= \LR{I\otimes C^{-1}}\c{Q\,du} \\
}$$
where $M$ is the [Commutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) Matrix associated with the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) of matrix equations.

Finally, calculate the gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{YY^TL} \\
  &= L:YY^T \\
d\phi &= L : \LR{dY\,Y^T+Y\,dY^T} \\
  &= 2L : dY\,Y^T \\
  &= 2LY : dY \\
  &= 2LY : \LR{2X\odot dX} \\
  &= 4\LR{X\odot LY} : dX \\
  &= 4\c{\vc{X\odot LY}} : dx \\
  &= 4\:\c{v} : dx \\
  &= 4\:v : \LR{I\otimes C^{-1}}Q\,du \\
  &= 4\:Q^T\LR{I\otimes C^{-1}}^Tv : du \\
\grad{\phi}{u}
  &= 4\:Q^T\LR{I\otimes C^{-1}}^Tv \\
}$$
Using this gradient, you can attempt a closed-form solution for the zero gradient condition, or you can use the gradient expression in a gradient descent algorithm.  The former is so complicated that it is likely impossible, while the latter is very simple.

Note that $Z$ depends on the *direction* of $U$ not its length. Thus every iteration should renormalize $U$ to prevent numerical overflows.

After calculating the optimal $u$ vector, the corresponding $W$ matrix can be reconstructed
$$\eqalign{
U &= \unvc{u} \\
Z &= U\LR{U^TU}^{-1/2} \\
X &= C^{-1}Z \\
W &= K^{-1}X \\
\\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon denotes the Frobenius product, which is incredibly useful in *Matrix Calculus*
$$\eqalign{
A:Z &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}Z_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TZ} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_{\c F}
\qquad \big\{{\rm\c{Frobenius}\:norm}\big\} \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:Z &= Z:A \\
A:Z &= A^T:Z^T \\
B:\LR{A^TZ} &= \LR{BZ^T}:A^T &= \LR{AB}:Z \\
}$$

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your patience to answer my doubts. But what I didn't understand was that the problem I was asking was constrained, and with gradient descent I didn't know how to solve the constrained problem. And, forgive me for being stupid, I want to find a matrix, and your answer seems to be getting a vector, doesn't that matter?

Comment: @gouchuan The columns of a matrix can be stacked to create a long vector (see the blue link above) and the long vector can be [un-stacked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805565) to reconstitute the original matrix. So my answer works with long vectors for convenience. But the really important idea is to transform the problem in terms of the constrained $W$ variable into a problem in terms of the unconstrained $U$ variable. *Lagrange Multipliers* are another way to reformulate constrained problems.

Comment: Sorry，there are some questions about the process of transforming constrained problems into unconstrained problems that I don't understand yet.I think the optimization process should be related to K, but the answer you gave is not related to K. Besides, I follow your steps and cannot push forward because K is not used in the subsequent process.

Comment: You first define Z in terms of unknown W, then construct Z in terms of unknown U, which makes me very confused.Because what I need to find after the optimal W is \begin{align}
&\text  W^TK
\end{align}, which means different K, this optimization problem should be different, and I can see from your answer that it does not satisfy the above.

Comment: @gouchuan The intermediate variables $(B,C,X,Y,Z)$ were introduced to facilitate the gradient calculation.
However, if you wish you can construct $W$ solely in terms of $(H,K,U)$
$$\large\eqalign{
W &= K^{-1}H^{-1/2}\;U(U^TU)^{-1/2} \\
}$$
It is trivial to verify that this construction satisfies the constraint for any choice of $U\;$